# How can I cast/fling media to a Plex for Kodi target?

Tags: video, streaming, ios, kodi, plex

On the Plex website https://www.plex.tv/apps/computer/kodi/#

> With the **Plex for Kodi** add-on, you get the Kodi experience for your big screen, powered by Plex Media Server, and enabling you to organize and access your beautiful media on any device, anywhere, anytime.
>
> ## Available Anywhere
>
> **Stream all of your media to all your devices, anytime, anywhere, with the same beautiful experience on all of them.** (iOS, Android, and Windows apps require a one-time unlock fee for full playback if you do not have a Plex Pass.)

I can't for the life of me get the Plex for Kodi player to show up on my list of player targets (from any device). I am a Plex Pass member.

How can I get this working? All ports are open on my local area network (other players work fine)

## Notes

Arch Linux (mentioned because while the question is independent of the operating system, perhaps the answer will not be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experience is not the same across devices (yet).

This functionality, which is covered by the clients under the name, *Plex Companion*, is currently not supported.

https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/283420/master-buglist-for-plex-for-kodi